# Normalize an array of floats into a certain range with keeping sign in Python

Tags: python, arrays, mapping, normalization

I have  an array of floats which can be negative and positive like this one:

```
[-23.5, -12.7, -20.6, -11.3, -9.2, -4.5, 2, 8, 11, 15, 17, 21]
```

I need to normalize this array into a range like this [-5,5].
The main point is that, I need to keep their sign (if its positive it should be mapped to positive and vice versa)

Comment: Well, then you have to define `normalize`. The underlying transformation is usually linear, so, of course, if the sum of your max and min is not zero, some numbers will have their signs changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-23.5, -12.7, -20.6, -11.3, -9.2, -4.5, 2, 8, 11, 15, 17, 21])
```

You want your data to span [-5, 5] and keep their sign, thus centered on zero. This means that the absolute max of the data would be one of the boundaries (of its original sign). Thus a simple transformation is to scale using this absolute maximum

```
scaled_a = a/abs(a).max()*5
```

output:

```
array([-5.        , -2.70212766, -4.38297872, -2.40425532, -1.95744681,
       -0.95744681,  0.42553191,  1.70212766,  2.34042553,  3.19148936,
        3.61702128,  4.46808511])
```